# Adding an image_tag for the inline background-image url in Rails 5 template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I need to set the background image inline using the style tag, but it needs to reference an image object and not a fixed image from the assets folder.  Below is my code to show what I am attempting to do.

```
<div class="background-image-holder" style="background: url(#{" image_path @product.photo_one_url(:original)"}); opacity: 1;">
  <%= image_tag(@product.photo_one_url(:medium)) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always prefer to use a `content_tag` if I'm including something dynamic like this, i.e.

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "background-image-holder", 
                      style: { background: "url('#{image_path(@product.photo_one_url(:original))}')", 
                               opacity: 1 } do %>
...
<% end >
```

I feel it reads nicer than using inline erb tags - personal preference, but another option for you.

Comment: This way does seem clean, but I am getting `background: url("undefined"); opacity: 1;` when I look at the image source in the console. I know the image path works because I tested it by displaying the image normally in the page.

Comment: Aha - I think you'll need to wrap the injected path in quotes, like: `"url('#{image_path(@product.photo_one_url(:original))}')"`. Sorry, my bad - haven't tested this. That, or escaped double quotes `\"`, should do the trick! (Answer updated to include this.)