# add background-image image_tag to div

Tags: css, ruby, image

I want to add image_tag @blog.image.url as a background image of the div
Here is what I tried but its not working

```
   <div class="blog" style="background-image: <%= image_tag @blog.image.url %>">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><h2 class="font"><%= @blog.textt%></h2><br>
    </div>
```

I tried this answer but it didn't works for me
[Adding an image_tag for the inline background-image url in Rails 5 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578595/adding-an-image-tag-for-the-inline-background-image-url-in-rails-5-template)

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: no error but no picture shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use `image_tag` when you can just use url.

```
 <div class="blog" style="background: url(<%= @blog.image.url %>">
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><h2 class="font"><%= @blog.textt%></h2><br>
 </div>
```

Or the more Rails way

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: "blog", style: "background: url(#{@blog.image.url}") do
  6.times{ content_tag(:br) }
  content_tag(:h2, class: 'font') { @blog.textt }
end %>
```